# JavaScript console on Parity: cannot execute commands (by pushing Enter button)

Tags: ether, parity

I am trying to open my Parity in Chrome after having set it up in internet explorer.

When I do so, it wants me to generate a new token:

> "Unable to make a connection to the Parity Secure API. To update your secure token or to generate a new one, run parity signer new-token and paste the generated token into the space below."

I fire up the Parity/Web3 console and type the command. When I push "enter" nothing happens. I cannot execute commands in the console. I just want to access the same data except through Chrome and not Internet Explorer.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Not the javascript console application in the browser. You need to open a terminal or command prompt. What operating system are you on? I can guide you.

Comment: Hit the windows key and type `cmd`, then a prompt opens, navigate to `cd "C:\Program Files\Ethcore\Parity\"` and execute `parity.exe signer new-token`.

Comment: Thanks 5chdn. I got the token. I put it into the input box but it is not allowing me to enter the code, there is no "Next" button for me to click.Do you think this is related to the initial error I posted about where I can't execute in the javascript console?

Comment: It should automatically forward you. You can also follow the direct link: `http://127.0.0.1:8180/#/auth?token=hKti-8s8N-wBiI-WXvA`

Comment: hmm. I sincerely appreciate your attentive help right now. I've tried it multiple ways with multiple tokens, and it doesn't seem to leave the token entry screen. I'll have to try again later and see if it works. There must be some setting in chrome or on my windows machine that is preventing the connection to the API, perhaps.